What free app or program (website) is best for building an interactive food web?
I'm trying to create an interactive food web to give a clear overview of Seal population dynamics based on diet. As food webs have a tendency to quickly become to comprehensive to be easily readable, I'm looking for a free app or program (website) that I can used to build my food web, whilst mitigating some of these issues. I would like to use the following tools:

Adding a picture of the target species.
Turning a picture into a hyperlink which brings you to a PDF-file with information on the targeted species.
Adding symbols, and arrows that are capable of linking-up between two photo's.
A list of the species with a checkbox next to them, that when checked only shows the checked species and their direct connections.
Or, The targeted species and their direct connections light up when you hover over it with the mouse.

If no such app or program exists with all these possibilities, what would you advice to do in order to decrease the issue of comprehensibility?

Welcome Bastiaan. We have a [softwarerecs.se] site that this might be more suited to - that being said, others may come up with some suggestions here. Please take our [tour] and refer to the [ask] section of the [help] before posting there to ensure that your question is in shape.
